# How to create a matrix using a repeated vector in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, vector

I have the following vector in vba:

```
If Blad1.Range("number").Value < 1 Then
        n = 1
Else
        n = Blad1.Range("number").Value
End If

curve = Blad2.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 3 + n - 1)).Value
```

And now I want to create a matrix in which the vector "curve" is repeated n times, that is, every row is the same. Is this possible in vba?

Comment: @BigBen I want it as a variable, I don't want it displayed in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a 2D array. This assumes that `n` is a positive integer.

When `n` equals 1, `curve` is not an array, and needs to be handled slightly differently.

```
Dim matrix As Variant
ReDim matrix(1 To n, 1 To n)

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = LBound(matrix, 1) To UBound(matrix, 1)
    For j = LBound(matrix, 2) To UBound(matrix, 2)
        If n = 1 Then
            matrix(i, j) = curve ' curve is not an array
        Else
            matrix(i, j) = curve(1, j)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

---

Side note:

```
curve = Blad2.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 3 + n - 1)).Value
```

can be simplified (and improved) to:

```
curve = Blad2.Cells(1, 3).Resize(, n).Value
```